# Showing $R\otimes M \cong M$ for $R$-modules $R,M$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

How to see that $R \otimes M \cong M$ if $R$ and $M$ are $R$-modules (with $R$ being a commutative ring with unity)?

I thought about defining $f: R\otimes M \rightarrow M$ by $(r,m) \mapsto rm$. Since $f(1,m) = m$ it follows that $f$ is surjective.

But to verify that $f$ is injective we would need to show that if $rm=0$ then $r=0$ or $m=0$ so that we could conclude that the kernel of $f$ is trivial (since $0 \otimes m= 0=r\otimes 0  $ for $m \in M, r\in R$).

But this would e.g. imply $M$ to be torsionfree what we did not require.

Comment: You have to consider $f(\sum_i r_i\otimes m_i)=\sum_i r_im_i=0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. To show it's injective, you have to show that, if $\;\sum r_i\otimes m_i\mapsto\sum r_im_i=0$, then $\;\sum r_i\otimes m_i=0$.

But that is because $\;\sum r_i\otimes m_i=\sum 1\otimes r_im_i=1\otimes0=0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\;r\otimes m\to rm=0\;$ then

$$r\times m=r(1\otimes m)=1\otimes rm=1\otimes0=0$$

and we've finished. I am assuming, of course, the tensor product is over $\;R\;$ without any further conditions.