# Is $M\otimes_{S} S(n)$ Isomorphic to $M(n)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

$S$ is a graded ring and $M$ is a graded $S$ module, let $S(n)$ denote the graded $S$ module by shifting the grading of $S$, i.e. $S(n)_i = S_{n+i}$.

Then do we have $M\otimes_{S} S(n)$ Isomorphic to $M(n)$?

If this is not true, is it true with the additional condition that $S$ is generated by $S_1$ as a $S_0$ algebra?

---

EDIT:

The reason that I am interested in this question is that I am trying to understand the proof of Hartshorne Chapter II Proposition 5.12 (b) which states *If $S$ is a graded ring, assume $S$ is generated by $S_1$ as a $S_0$ algebra. For any graded $S$ module $M$, $\tilde{M}(n)\cong \widetilde{M(n)}$*, Where in the proof Hartshorne said use the fact that $\widetilde{M\otimes_{S} N}\cong \tilde{M}\otimes_{O_X} \tilde{N}$.

I am able to show this fact, but I think Hartshorne was trying to let $N$ be $S(n)$, then by the isomorphism, we have $\tilde{M}(n) \cong \widetilde{M\otimes_{S} S(n)}$. Then if I can show $M\otimes_{S} S(n)\cong M(n)$, then it is done.

Comment: What grading would you define on $M \otimes_S S(n)$ ?

Comment: I think there is only one possible grading that is consistent with tensor product operation where you add the degree of the two components together.

Comment: Yes, that's right. You don't need any assumptions.

Comment: Hi Qiaochu, I was just not sure if multiplication of the simple tensor gives an isomorphism, I don’t see why that has to be subjective.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Hi Qiaochu, I am not sure if it help, but in general we don’t have $\tilde{S(n)} \otimes \tilde{S(m)}$ isomorphic to $\widetilde{S(n+m)}$ without the assumption that $S$ is generated by $S_1$. Then if we have $S(n)\otimes_{S} S(m)$ isomorphic to $S(n+m)$ for free then I think it is a contradiction?

Comment: Does your definition of tensor product satisfy $M \otimes_S S \cong M$? If not it sounds very funny to me. If so all we need is that grading shift commutes with tensor product.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comments, it is just standard tensor product, but how do I show grading shift commutes with tensor product?

Comment: I think this question ought to be improved in a few ways: first, you should explain why you're worried about this - the stuff about tensor products of sheaves makes it easier to understand why you're having an issue here. Second, you should include your thoughts and attempts at solving this ("I think there is only one possible grading...", "I was just not sure if multiplication of the simple tensor gives an isomorphism...") in the question - this sort of thing would make it much easier for people to address your issues instead of having to ask you so many questions in the comments.

Comment: @KReiser Hi KReiser, thank you for the advice! I had tried to update the question, the reason that I did not put the reason that I asked this question originally is that I thought this is probably a very easy and elementary question that I am probably just stupid and did not get the proof.

Comment: Even if it was easy or your brain temporarily deserted you while thinking about it (I prefer to avoid using the word "stupid" to describe moments like these), there's interesting math here contained in your motivation for asking about this. Please don't feel afraid to share the background of your question here in the future - this makes interactions here better for everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true with no conditions on $M$ and $S$: the map $M\otimes_S S(n)\to M(n)$ given by sending $m\otimes s \mapsto ms$ where $m\in M_d$, $s\in S(n)_e$, and $ms\in M(n)_{d+e}$ is an isomorphims. The proof is the same as in the [ungraded case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1765468/showing-r-otimes-m-cong-m-for-r-modules-r-m): using the rules for manipulating tensors, rewrite $m\otimes s$ as $ms\otimes 1$. Keeping track of the grading, we see that if $m\in M_d$ and $s\in S(n)_e=S_{n+e}$, then $ms\in M_{d+n+e}= M(n)_{d+e}$ and all is exactly as it should be.

---

It is understandable to be curious about what's going on with the sheafy version, though - there can be some interesting things that happen there when the condition "$S$ is generated by $S_1$ as an $S_0$-algebra" is removed. For instance, Hartshorne's proof that $\widetilde{M}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X} \widetilde{N} \cong \widetilde{M\otimes_S N}$ requires that $S$ is generated in degree one. There is [always a canonical map](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01MK) from the LHS to the RHS but it need not be an isomorphism, and there are [cases](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01ML) where there is *no* isomorphism.

One source I like which explains this situation is the Stacks Project, specifically their sections on [quasi-coherent sheaves on Proj](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01MJ) and [invertible sheaves on Proj](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01MM).

For a more explicit description of what "generated in degree one" buys you for sheaves of the form $\mathcal{O}(n)$, the key lemma here is the following:

> **Lemma** ([Stacks 01MS](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01MS)): Let $S$ be a graded ring, and set $X=\operatorname{Proj} S$. Let $f\in S$ be homogeneous of degree $d>0$. The sheaves $\mathcal{O}(nd)|_{D(f)}$ are invertible, and in fact trivial, for all $n\in \Bbb Z$.

When $S$ is generated by $S_1$, this means that $X$ can be covered by open sets of the form $D(f)$ for $f\in S_1$ and thus all $\mathcal{O}(n)$ are invertible and everything works like it ought to.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I am just not sure why can we rewrite $m\otimes s$ as $ms\otimes 1$, because I thought $1$ is an element of degree zero hence is not in $S(n)$, maybe my brain ceases working again.

Comment: This is part of the definition of the tensor product: if $A,B$ are $R$-modules (with $R$ commutative) with elements $a,b$ respectively then $r(a\otimes b)=ra\otimes b = a\otimes rb$ for any $r\in R$. Next, $1$ is an element of $S(n)$, except it's in degree $-n$: remember that $S(n)_i=S_{n+i}$, so $S(n)_{-n}=S_0$ and $1$ is certainly in there.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I was mistaken the graded module to be direct sum from degree zero (just like the definition of graded ring). Sorry for wasting your time, but still a lot of appreciation for this good answer!

Comment: Also, I want to thank you because this really helps correct my understandings and this is actually a very very crucial definition.